# Суммирование данных в одной таблице и перенос суммы в другую

Tags: excel

Необходимо, чтобы числа записанные в каждой строке этой таблицы суммировались

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И  сумма отправлялась в строку второй таблицы, находящейся в этом же файле

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Excel вообще не разбираюсь, помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во второй таблице выделяем ячейку, в которой должен получиться результат. В меню выбираем "Вставка"-"Функции". Нужна функция СУММ(). После того как выбрали функцию, выделяем мышкой или пишем вручную диапазон суммируемых значений и нажимаем клавишу Enter.